# When use two col-12 classes in Bootstrap4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

When i try use two col-12 classes in Bootstrap
like this:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html class="h-100" lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
        .navbar {
            height: 3rem;
        }
        .main-container {
            height: calc(100vh - 3rem);
        }
        @media (min-width: 768px) {
            
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body class="h-100">
      <header class="navbar navbar-light bg-info">
          header
      </header>
      <div class="container-fluid main">
          <div class="row main-container">
             <div class="col-md-3 col-12 bg-light bd-sidebar">
                A area
            </div>
             <div class="col-md-9 col-12">
                B area
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I find my page will show when i use on mobile screen:
[image: mobile screen result]
I think the size of A area should be max-content. And where did the blank content under A area come form?

Comment: Can't reproduce on Bootstrap 4 & 5.

Answer (score 1):

Your `.main-container` have height to almost full screen. If screen width is small, the column elements will be align vertical instead of horizontal as specify in `col-md-3 col-12`. And when they align in vertical, those 2 elements will be align evenly by (parent height / 2) because default `align-content` of flex is `normal`.

If you want to keep your height on `.main-container`, add the value of `align-content` to `flex-start`.
See reference on [css tricks website](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```css
.navbar {
    height: 3rem;
}

.main-container {
    height: calc(100vh - 3rem);
    align-content: flex-start;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header class="navbar navbar-light bg-info">
    header
</header>
<div class="container-fluid main">
    <div class="row main-container">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-12 bg-light bd-sidebar">
            A area
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9 col-12">
            B area
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

[See it on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7sgw9kzu/).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like, the problem is:

```
.main-container {
    height: calc(100vh - 3rem);
}
```

A solution could be:

```
/* small mobile :320px. */
@media (max-width: 767px) {
 .main-container {
    height: 100px; /* for example */
 }
}
```